# How to scrape webpage through the client?

Tags: javascript, html, youtube, web-scraping, user-data

I'm trying to make a web tool that assembles specific parts of other sites onto one canvas. As an example, I'm wanting my own canvas to show my Youtube subscriptions (user specific data) and my favorite subreddit's listings (non-user specific). I'm trying to do this without using an API, so that it can be plugged into any site that has user-data (like Facebook, Twitter). Is it possible to scrape that data *through* the client so that I can avoid needing authorization? I'm not altering or reading the data in any way, only re-displaying it in a more pleasing way. The only leads I have on making this work is that it may be possible with a web extension or **maybe** a website with a custom Google Polymer element and scraping with JS (idk if that's even possible). Is this the right path?

Otherwise I'd have to get the data **for** the client user through my authorized and approved site, when that really seems like overkill. Thanks for the help!

Comment: The rules concerning cross-origin requests will make this impossible for most websites. You can't access web pages from other domains without the explicit complicity of the other domain. Google won't even show in an `iframe` nowdays.

Comment: @spender Well then what about an extension? It must be possible somehow, it's only 'remixing' data that the user has in their browser. If an extension wouldn't be possible, then would a whole new program/browser be possible?

Comment: I think a question that could be paraphrased with "how do I build a content aggregating website/extension/application" is too broad for SO. By a very large margin.

Comment: Post in current state is very broad and is not good fit for SO. Indeed you can scrape web sites from client (non-web-page) code - but you need to decide on approach first (and try) for question to be on-topic for SO.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov okay, thanks for the help. If I was to use non-web-page code, then in what form? I'd assume through and extension or JS? I'd just like to avoid mapping out an API at all costs. I just want to get what the user sees usually on a page, then put it on another for them.  

Sorry for the broad question, it's just that for me it's the starting route that I'm having trouble finding when developing, once I find it then I can usually take it from there. Thanks again!

Comment: @spender You're right, I am basically asking that question now that you summarize it. I just don't know enough terminology or domain expertise to know where to start. My mistake.

Comment: That is exactly what "too broad" means - too many choices and it is up to *you* to decide what you are comfortable with.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I see, it's like asking yes/no questions instead of determinant ones. Well then, I'm currently exploring [Artoo](https://medialab.github.io/artoo/), would that be a beneficial tool in this project?